# Is there any particular architecture, should we use in Flutter mobile application development?

Tags: model-view-controller, dart, flutter

I have been using Flutter for five months to develop a application which users are logged in an can view and get contacted with another user. I have an intention to grow up that app further to facilitate users with personal chats and file sharing portal. I thought it's better to develop the application in a bit organized manner. So I want to know that is there any specific architecture (such as MVC in web development) which is good to be used in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Flutter is a relatively new framework that is still an open argument. There are already dozens of articles about Flutter patterns/architectures out there, and of course no one is the best one. As usual it really depends on what you're building, your app requirements, and of course your personal preferences.

Here some resources I suggest to take a look at:

- [Build reactive mobile apps in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-io/build-reactive-mobile-apps-in-flutter-companion-article-13950959e381)
- [Flutter Architecture : Implement MVP Pattern](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-architecture-implement-a-mvp-pattern-8ab78b75f2d4)
- [Flutter Architecture Samples](http://fluttersamples.com/)